# incrementing/decrementing button.onclicklistener

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I have an activity class that is implementing `onClickListener` **Interface**

I am not able to find out what to do next. 
My aim is to have a overriding view method `onClick(View v)` that will increment the flag from 1 to 5 **different uris** (say 5 urls) on click of **UP** button and decrement from uri-5 to uri-1 on the click of **DOWN** button. It'll dependent on the position of each button at any instance. 
Please help me with a clue.

I had tried is as below:-

```
Button up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button down = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

up.setOnClickListener(this);
down.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v) {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this 
make a static variable

```
static int count=0;
```

in up

```
  if(count=<5)
   Log.e("Output" ,"uri-"+count++);
```

in down

```
if(count>0)
 Log.e("Output" ,"uri-"+count--);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
static int flag = 0;  // Global variable in class

/** Code to use in onCreate()  **/
Button up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button down = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);    
up.setOnClickListener(this);
down.setOnClickListener(this);

/** Override method in class **/
public void onClick(View v)
{
  if (v == up)
  {
    if (flag < 5)
       flag++;
  }
  else if (v == down)
  {
    if (flag > 0)
       flag--;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
int currentURLIndex = 0;
int urlCount = 5;

public void onClick(View v) {
  if(v == up){
    currentURLIndex = Math.min(++currentURLIndex, urlCount);
  } else if if(v == down){
     currentURLIndex = Math.max(--currentURLIndex, 0);
   }
}
```

Comment: i am observing @iTech i very active today Answering every question in stackoverflow good work keep it up

Comment: :) This is my prime time for SO